# Boolean variable becomes command-line option

Tags: bash

Is there a more succinct way to do this with **bash**?

```
if [[ ${BOOL} == true ]]; then
    OPTION="--option"
else
    OPTION=
fi

command ${OPTION}
```

`BOOL` is a string value guaranteed to be either: `true` or `false`

If `true` there should be an option.
If `false` there should be no option.

Comment: Do you intend to pass an empty variable to `command` on `false`? Remember `true` and `false` in the context `bash` are just plain strings, not built-ins BTW

Comment: Do you intend to do a string comparison or a logical true assertion?

Comment: BOOL is a string with value: `true` or `false`

Comment: @Inian Correct. `true` should result in an option, `false` should result in no option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shorter than the other answers:

```
OPTION=$($BOOL && echo --option)
```

Is it better? I'm not sure.

As long as it works and you understand it, I don't see a reason to change it.

Comment: Wow, I did not know that bash would understand the strings `true` and `false` as boolean values. Neat!

Comment: @datashaman - It doesn't, it's weirder than that! `true` and `false` are bash builtin commands (like `logout` or `echo`), Jared's example works because `true` always returns zero, and `false` always returns 1. The sub-shell will simply execute the contents of `$BOOL` and if the result is zero, the `echo --option` command is then run.

Comment: @KarlNicoll Ahhh, that makes more sense now!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
OPTION=[[ ${BOOL} == true ]] && "--option"
command ${OPTION}
```